# Wordpress best plugin for forum

Tags: wordpress, plugins

What is the best plugin for forum  in wordpress

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Questions asking for the 'best' invite opinions which is discouraged on this site. Please visit SO Help Center and the FAQs on what type of questions are allowed >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress is the best plugin for the forum